# Ubuntu Default Won't Load After Installing Cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon

I just installed Cinnamon this morning, but I didn't like what I saw after I logged in. I logged out and tried logging in with Ubuntu Default, but it gives a "Ubuntu Failed to Load" pop up error.

I managed to uninstall Cinnamon and I am now logged in through Gnome Fallback. I want to go back to default. How do I fix this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I had to do a sudo apt-get autoremove and it removed all the dependencies. Everything got back to normal.